# Filter by Last column in Pig Latin - when schema is not specified

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to put a generic script in Pig Latin where I need to filter data based on the last column.

My data-sets will have varying columns counts, where I will filter based on the last column.

Is there any way we can get the last column in Pig.

```
master = LOAD '/user/data/usps/dataset_1/' using PigStorage(',') ;
B = FILTER master BY last_column is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't by using pigstorage. But you can write your own custom loader (quite easy to be honest) to parse data and name the last column "last_column"